# \PARstart not working (IEEEtran)

Tags: templates, ieeetran, journal-publishing

Ok, I am useing the IEEEtran document class. It is in journal mode and I get this error when I try to use `\PARstart`:

```
./main.tex:148: Undefined control sequence.
l.148   \PARstart
            {T}{his}
```

I am using overleaf to compile it.

Comment: Welcome to tex.se. Can you edit your question to include an MWE that produces your error. More information about MWE [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe)

Comment: I think it should be `\IEEEPARstart`

Comment: @egreg. That does the trick for me. Maybe you should post it as an answer.

Comment: This question is exactly asked like I would, and the answer in the comments also solves my issue. I don't get why it's closed.